# B2C support for Java Web Application authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

When I go through Azure AD B2C documentation, I notice there is no code example or mention of Java Web apps and APIs as part of examples. We have good examples for nodejs and dotnet apps, but Java web app example is missing:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples#web-apps-and-apis

Does this mean that Java web applications must implement B2C authentication at the protocol REST call level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Java samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp):

- Java web application using the MSAL4J to sign in users with Azure AD
- A Java web application using Spring Security to sign in users with Azure AD
- A Java web application using the MSAL4J to sign in users **Azure AD B2C**

They use the [MSAL4J library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java).